# How can I access outsourced classes from my Form1. cs in C#

Tags: c#, class, optimization

I am creating an application using Windows Forms. So that my `Form1.cs` does not become too large, I would like to outsource some functions. So that I don't process the function in the `Button1_Click`-EventHandler, but only call the method for it. I have problems accessing the methods from `Form1.cs` to the methods which I have outsourced to classes. How do I add the class to my namespace and how do I access it? There are perhaps even better variants than outsourcing the functions to classes. For Example.

Comment: Could you show the code that produces the error, and provide a [mre]

Comment: If the only reason for you to move the code into functions in other classes is to reduce cognitive complexity, why not just split it in the relevant class as private methods? Creating a [god class](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/god-object-a-code-smell/) will make your code smell...

Comment: Wait. First thing first. Study how namespaces work. Study how classes are instanced. Study member visibility. Understand these concepts in C# as well as in OOP in general.

Comment: I have now solved it with namespaces and classes. A main namespace and an under-namespace where I have added the class. Can access the method from the main namespace. The only problem now is that my class in the under-namespace can't access the Windows Forms controls that are in the main namespace.

Comment: You are running too fast. You should learn the language with console applications first and _later_ UI programming. You may even learn about interfaces, dependencies and then about MVC pattern.